# Eclipse RCP update only one variable from MVC model

Tags: java, model-view-controller, eclipse-rcp, jface, updatemodel

How can you update only a specific model valu, and not all the binded values?

For all the binded values one can use:

```
bindingContext.updateModels();
```

But how to do the same, but only on one of the bound model variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will do this indirectly. You should bind your model values to SWT controls using BeanProperties and not PojoProperties. Now, in all of your setters, you should set the value like this:

```
public void setValue(Object value) {
    firePropertyChange("value", this.value, this.value = value);
}
```

You should implement the firePropertyChange method in a super class or a Support class using the PropertyChangeSupport class in Java.
Now, any time the value on the model side is changed, the corresponding control on your view is automatically updated.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I did, sory for not posting solution myself :).